# Can I limit polygon line length (like 100m) in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My Requirement is to limit the polygon line length based on the given input. I've tried the following code but I am not able to successfully limit the length of the line.

[image]

The image above is the type of line segment that I would like to limit the length of.

```
Var drawingManager;

var Map;
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});

var polyOptions = {
    draggable: true, // turn off if it gets annoying
    editable: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
};

drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
    },
    polylineOptions: {
        editable: false
    },
    rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
    circleOptions: polyOptions,
    polygonOptions: polyOptions,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    alert();
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {

        });
    }
     google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'set_at', function() {
        // complete functions
        alert();
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'insert_at', function() {
        // complete functions
        alert();
      });
});
```

Comment: What given input?  Do all the polylines that make up the polygon have the same limit? Does the limit apply to the total length of the polylines?  Please clarify what you need and what you have tried to code.

Comment: User will give the length of polygon. Example if i need to draw a polygon with the length of 50 meter. The map should allow to draw a polygon with 50 m @geocodezip

Comment: How will they give the length of the polygon?  How do you define the "length" of a polygon?

Comment: Length mean only the outer line length of the polygon @geocodezip

Comment: You may want to look at [SO-4180187](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180187/googlemaps-polyline-length-in-v3). It would be a good read I think.